# Why this submit function in Meteorjs doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, meteor

I have a form which consists of 7 questions. I ask them individually using display:none. But the problem is that submit function doesn't work. When I click it, it just redirects back to the first question and url turns to - http://localhost:3000/?problem=&why1=&why2=&why3=&why4=&why5=&solution=&submit-all=Answer . I really need help with this please. Below is code for HTML template and JavaScript submit function to submit in Problems collection.

```html
<template name="submitProblem">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-page">
      <form class="text-center">
        <div id="submit-problem">
          <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="problem" id="problem" placeholder="What's the problem ?"/>
          <input type="button" id="route" value="Find Its Route" class="route btn btn-sample">
        </div>

         ...
        submit-why1 - submit-why4
         ...

        <div id="submit-why5" class="hidden">
          <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" id="why5" class="" name="why5" placeholder="This problem exists, because..."/>
          <input type="button" value="Answer" class="btn-success btn answer5">
          <button class="btn back5 back-btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-3x"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div id="submit-solution" class="hidden">
          <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="solution" id="solution" placeholder="What could be the best solution ?"/>
            
          <input type="submit" id="submit-all" name="submit-all" value="Answer" class="btn btn-primary submit-all">

          <button class="btn back6 back-btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-3x"></i></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
Template.submitProblem.events({
  'submit .submit-all':function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var problem = $(event.target).find('[name=problem]').val();
    var why1 = $(event.target).find('[name=why1]').val();
    var why2 = $(event.target).find('[name=why2]').val();
    var why3 = $(event.target).find('[name=why3]').val();
    var why4 = $(event.target).find('[name=why4]').val();
    var why5 = $(event.target).find('[name=why5]').val();
    var solution = $(event.target).find('[name=solution]').val();

   Problems.insert({
      problem: problem,
      why1: why1,
      why2: why2,
      why3: why3,
      why4: why4,
      why5: why5,
      solution: solution,
      submitdate: new Date()
    });

    console.log(problem + why1 + why2 + why3 + why4 + why5 + solution);

    Router.go('submitted');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `event` as the first parameter to your handler:

```js
submit: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Otherwise it won't be defined, the default action (a POST) won't be prevented, and your page will reload.

Comment: Thanks, actually it works without it, but I just realized I have to submit a form - 'submit form': function(event) not a button like I did instead in the code above.

Comment: Yes good point. I modified the solution to just use `submit`, as `form` here is redundant.